# "ignoreDocumentNotFound", "readCompleteInput" query options in explain

Tags: arangodb

When I use "explain" on an insert query I get two query options that seems not to be documented:

- ignoreDocumentNotFound
- readCompleteInput

What are these options for and what they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice to see you like our [`db._explain()`](https://docs.arangodb.com/latest/AQL/ExecutionAndPerformance/ExplainingQueries.html) Facility ;-)

To answer your question one has to know that explain re-uses a backend functionality that is also used for different purposes:

- distribute AQL queries in ArangoDB clusters
- analyse what the optimizer did with queries in Unittests

The later will explain queries, and check whether certain assumptions over the query plan are still valid.
The `ignoreDocumentNotFound` and `readCompleteInput` flags are exactly intended for that purpose, so the unittests can revalidate whether certain assumptions for the query are still true.

Since they don't contain additional value for the end user, they're not documented. One could argue whether explain should hide them to avoid irretations